# c# - listview does not shows different icons for all item/images?

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I am trying to make an image gallery in C#.
I am having a problem in viewing thumbnails of images in a `ListView`.
One image shows for all images in image list.

This is a ScreenShot:

[image: Screen Shot]

And this is the code:

```
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    int i = 0;
    filename.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
    images.Images.Add(i.ToString(),Image.FromFile(path));
    ImageView.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),i);
    richTextBox1.Text += path + Environment.NewLine;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each list view item has an ImageIndex property.  By default its a 0, so it would show the first image.

While its unclear what your data types are, I think this is what you want.

```
int i = 0;

foreach (string path in filePaths)
    {
        filename.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
        images.Images.Add(i.ToString(),Image.FromFile(path));
       ImageView.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),i);

        richTextBox1.Text += path + Environment.NewLine;
        i++;
    }
```